# Style issues after ng-include

Tags: html, angularjs

I am building a huge one-page site, so I wanted to keep my code clean. I decided to part it into several HTML files and include them in one main index.html. So I wrote a snippet of code in index.html and everything worked fine. However, as I tried to include this snippet from another file, my web page did not appear properly.

Here is the snippet I wrote:

```
<div class="hidden-sm hidden-xs" id="containerStart">
    <div id="left" class="start">
        <img src="../pics/svg/Logo%20links.svg" class="logoStart hidden img-responsive" id="logoLeft">
    </div>
    <div id="right" class="start">
        <img src="../pics/svg/Logo%20rechts.svg" class="logoStart hidden img-responsive" id="logoRight">
    </div>
    <div id="captions">
        <h3 class="hidden" id="mivalStart">Mival</h3>
        <h5 class="hidden" id="mivalMotto">Innovative Vertriebskonzepte</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
    <!--Bootstrap css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!--Start animation css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/start.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/letterFx.css">
    <title>Mival</title>
</head>
<body ng-app>
    <!--Intro-->
    <div ng-include src="'intro.html'"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-letterfx.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/start.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Maybe you know any solutions for my problem?

Comment: Did you already try `ng-include="intro.html"`?

Comment: Have you tried it without the div: <ng-include src="your-source"></ng-include>  ?

Comment: @AustinMullins - `ng-include` expects an interpolated value so you have to include string constants in quotes.

Comment: Can you explain what style issues you are having? "Did not appear properly" is vague.

Comment: Also...Isn't it better to include the javascript libraries on the header?

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using? and what is in your `start.js` file. I ask because you have `ng-app` without explicitly referencing any module name.

Comment: @MauricioMoraes - no. JS files need to go at the bottom unless they absolutely must be in place before the document renders. Because web pages are processed from top to bottom, having JS at the top will make the page render more slowly. Putting them at the bottom means it can render quickly and then bootstrap with JS.

Comment: @Josh, Thats interesting. And does his ng-app bootstraps correctly if he include the lib inside? Other question... Is there any problem if the ng-app has no param (say ng-app="somethingApp"), as he did ?

Comment: @MauricioMoraes - the module name is optional when using `ng-app` but is in practice pretty useless without it. It will create an anonymous module, if you will, and you can still use directives and such, but you won't be able to take advantage of controllers and services.

Comment: @MauricioMoraes All the basic concepts pointed out worked in Chrome for me [in this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jtHX1HZxkHcSiZ71RgKf?p=preview).

Comment: Which leads us back to: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Thanks Guys, that was a class!

Comment: Ok, guys, thx for your answers. I have solved the problem. My style did not work properly because of another additional div I created, which should contain the snippet. So I just took one div out of the snippet, and included the rest of the code in there. I must admit it was a really silly mistake.